How do I stop MAMP from opening a page that redirects to Dropbox every time I open it?
As in Title, every time I startup MAMP, the first thing that happens is that it opens automatically a web page directed to a dropbox authorization page. Is there a way to stop that from happening?
I dont use Dropbox, and i checked that the feature was turned off in mamp settings, but it isn't enough.

try: Preferences / Cloud / Off
